# Unable to Open Chrome WebDriver with Selenium for Python

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium, ubuntu, webdriver

I am trying the following script and can't get it to open Webdriver:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome')
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()
```

This produces the following error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome('/usr/bin/google-chrome')
  File "/home/joseph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 68, in __init__
    self.service.start()
  File "/home/joseph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 98, in start
    self.assert_process_still_running()
  File "/home/joseph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 111, in assert_process_still_running
    % (self.path, return_code)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Service /usr/bin/google-chrome unexpectedly exited. Status code was: 1
```

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 running on Windows 10.  Any ideas what this could be?

EDIT:

Now I'm doing this with chromedriver, which I unzipped to the same directory as the script.

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
```

I get the following error instead of the previous one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "scraper.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver')
  File "/home/joseph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 75, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/home/joseph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 154, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/joseph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 243, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/joseph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 312, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/joseph/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.36.540471 (9c759b81a907e70363c6312294d30b6ccccc2752),platform=Linux 4.4.0-43-Microsoft x86_64)
```

Comment: Are you running this with Chrome Driver? (its a separate executable that WebDriver uses to control Chrome) [(Download Page)](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads)

Comment: @Aristu  I am now, but it still doesn't work.  See updated post please.

Comment: your using an incompatible version of chromedriver for your chrome browser.

Comment: make sure  chromedriver.exe file is in your root python directory

Answer (score 0):

While working with *Selenium v3.11.0*, *ChromeDriver v2.36* and *Chrome v64.x* you have to download the latest *ChromeDriver* from the  [ChromeDriver - WebDriver for Chrome](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) and place it within your system. Next while initializing the *WebDriver* and the *WebBrowser* you have to mention the absolute path of the *ChromeDriver* as follows :

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='/path/to/chromedriver')
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.quit()
```

> **Note** : At the end of your *Test Execution* instead of `close()` invoke the `quit()` method so the *WebDriver* and *WebBrowser* both are destroyed.

Comment: I changed my script to use chromedriver and it still isn't working.  Please see updated post.

Comment: Can you try with the absolute path?

Answer (score 0):

You may need to try various versions of the driver depending on version of chrome. Also, make sure your path is correct and pointing to executable driver file(.exe)
`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='./chromedriver/chromedriver.exe')`